# How to save the details of the account chosen in account chooser dialog box?

Tags: android, xml, google-api, google-account

Below code shows the Account chooser dialog box for the first time when i login to my app and then i choose an account from it .But whichever account i choose ,i want to show its details(**email_id,user_name,user_profile pic**) on the Navigation drawer header .How to show the details of the account?? .

**MainActivity.java**

```
  public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    RecyclerView rvHome;
    RVAdapter rvAdapter;
    LinearLayoutManager llm;
    ArrayList<Doc> docs = new ArrayList<>();
    private boolean loading = true;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private long numFound = 0;
    private boolean isFilter = false;
    private String category = "ad_category:3";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;
    private boolean mIntentInProgress;
    private static final int PROFILE_PIC_SIZE = 400;
    CircleImageView profileImage;
    TextView userName;
    TextView userEmail;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private boolean isConnected;
    String SCOPE = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile";
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTIVITY_TRANSITIONS);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setTitle("Popular Design");
        setColorIndex();
        setColors(this, colorIndex);
        overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        rvHome = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_home);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        rvHome.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rvAdapter = new RVAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        rvHome.setAdapter(rvAdapter);
        rvHome.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loading_progress);
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setCancelable(false);
        MyShopApplication application = (MyShopApplication) getApplication();
        Tracker mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.USER_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        View hView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.home);
        profileImage = (CircleImageView) hView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        userName = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        userEmail = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.user_email);
        userName.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.USER_NAME, ""));
        userEmail.setText(sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.USER_EMAIL, ""));
        String image_url = sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.USER_EMAIL, "");
        if (!image_url.trim().matches("")) {
            Picasso.with(this).load(image_url).into(profileImage);
        }
        checkPermissions();
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .build();
        Utils.TrackTiming(MyShopApplication.getInstance().getDefaultTracker(),AppConstants.ACTIVITY_LOAD,"MAIN_ACTIVITY",System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime,AppConstants.LOADED);

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[image: Navigation_drawer]

Answer (score 1):

Next you have to start sign in flow by using Intent.

```
public void startSignIn(){
    Intent signInIntent =     Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(.   mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent,     GOOGLE_SIGN_IN);
}
```

Now implement onActivityResult() to get the result.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent.
        if (requestCode == GOOGLE_SIGN_IN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }
```

Now you can get account details from the result object.

```
private void     handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    //Check if signin result is successful
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct =     result.getSignInAccount();
                testView.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
Uri profilePictureUri = acct.getPhotoUrl();
//You can get other details like email,Id etc.
      
    } else {
        // Signed out.
       
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to call these methods and intent in the `onCreate` method??

Comment: You can call startActivityReault() on buttons click event if you are using custom button for google signin, i have updated answer.

Comment: No ,I want that automatically the dialog box appears as soon as i open my app and it asks for sign in.And When i choose an account then it should save the details and show it on the navigation drawer .

Comment: In that case you can call startSignIn() method in onCreate(), but make sure you call it after configuring GoogleApiClient.

Comment: My above code shows the dialog box automatically as soon as my app open .But i just want to know how to save those account details and  show them in navigation header .

Comment: Once user successfully signin onActivityResult() will be called, you can just implement onActivityResult() and handleSignInResult() methods from my code.

Comment: It is not working for me.It is showing invalid Api request error.

Comment: It has worked .I didnt  added the signin api to my google api client.Thanks :)

Comment: I wanted to ask one thing that by applying the above code ,whenever i open my app i get the FragmentDialog of loading the account details if i tap outside that FragmentDialog before loading the Account details then my account details are not shown,I have to wait everytime for the Account details to be loaded ,I wanted to load the account details for the first time when i open my app ,and for the second time and so on it should show the account details without loading the FragmentDialog

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences to store user data and check a condition in onCreate() method to check if userId is stored already, if not stored run google api code for login else dont do login stuff and directly fetch data from SharedPreferences and load your views.